# Google Drive API doesn't keep user signed in after user chooses account

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

In one section of my android application, user can import CSV files into the application. To do so, users must allow the app to have access to their Google drive. I accomplish this by using the Google Drive API Sign in, and allow users to only be able to choose CSV files.When in debug mode, the below code works perfectly. However after release of the app the users are never logged in.

in debug mode:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFj_fn13x2c&feature=youtu.be

released version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq2POP43waM

Permissions:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;

import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResourceClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Metadata;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filters;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.SearchableField;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.Custom_Classes.AddAndEditMethods;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.Custom_Classes.CSVExporter;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.Custom_Classes.CustomDateParser;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.Custom_Classes.CustomRegex;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.StaticVariables;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.adapter.CustomEventObject;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.dialog_fragments.NotificationSettings;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.notification_package.CustomNotification;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.sqllite.DBHandler;
import com.project.danielo.eventer.R;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;


public class SettingsFragments extends Fragment {

    public SettingsFragments(){

    }

    private View settingsView;
    Button 
            btnImportEvents, btnDriveSettings;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    GoogleApiClient apiClient;
    private static final String TAG = "Google drive activity";
    private static  final int  REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 15;
    private static final  int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 16;
    private  static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_ITEM = 1;


    private DriveId driveId;
    private DriveClient driveClient;
    private OpenFileActivityOptions openFileActivityOptions;
    private DriveResourceClient resourceClient;
    private TaskCompletionSource<DriveId> mOpenItemTaskSource;
    private DriveContents driveContents;
    private Metadata metadata;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        signIn();
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        settingsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_settings_fragment, null, false);

        btnImportEvents = (Button)settingsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_import_events);
        btnDriveSettings = (Button)settingsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_google_drive_settings);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)settingsView.findViewById(R.id.settings_progress_bar);




          /*Upon this button click, the app checks if user is logged 
        * before giving user access to Google Drive account
        */
        btnImportEvents.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isConnectedToTheInternet()) {
                    openPleaseConnectToInternet();

                }else{
                   if(!isUserSignedInToGoogleDriveAccount()){
                       openSignInGoogleDriveAccountDialog();
                   }else{

                       openFileChooser();

                   }

                }

            }
        });
        /*Upon this button click, the app logs user of current Google Drive account
        * and opens choose account dialog
        */
        btnDriveSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isConnectedToTheInternet()) {
                    openPleaseConnectToInternet();

                }else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        /*
                        /user is signed in, so we must initialize sign in client and sign out to reopen Google Drive Account chooser
                         */
                            GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                                    new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                                            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                                            .build();

                    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(),signInOptions);
                            signInClient.signOut();
                            signIn();

                }

            }
        });
        return settingsView;
    }

    /***********************START OF IMPORT EVENTS METHODS**************************/
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    // Sign-in may fail or be cancelled by the user. For this sample, sign-in is
                    // required and is fatal. For apps where sign-in is optional, handle
                    // appropriately
                    return;
                }

                Task<GoogleSignInAccount> getAccountTask =
                        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                if (getAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
                    initializeDriveClient(getAccountTask.getResult());

                } 
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                   loadCurrentFile();
                }

                break;


        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    //Google drive sign in
    private void signIn(){

        Set<Scope> requiredScopes = new HashSet<>(2);
        requiredScopes.add(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
        requiredScopes.add(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);
        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());

       if (signInAccount != null && signInAccount.getGrantedScopes().containsAll(requiredScopes)) {
            initializeDriveClient(signInAccount);
        } else {
            GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                    new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                            .build();
           GoogleSignInClient  signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(), signInOptions);
            startActivityForResult(signInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);

        }
    }
    //list files in drive
    private void openFileChooser(){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        OpenFileActivityOptions openOptions =
                new OpenFileActivityOptions.Builder()
                       .setSelectionFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/csv"))
                      //  .setMimeType(mimeTypes)
                        .setActivityTitle("Choose a CSV file")
                        .build();

        driveClient.newOpenFileActivityIntentSender(openOptions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<IntentSender>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IntentSender intentSender) {

                        try {
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    intentSender,
                                    REQUEST_CODE_OPENER,
                                    /* fillInIntent= */ null,
                                    /* flagsMask= */ 0,
                                    /* flagsValues= */ 0,
                                    /* extraFlags= */ 0,
                                    null);
                            ;
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent.", e);
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create OpenFileActivityIntent.", e);
            }
        });

    }


    private void initializeDriveClient(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {

        driveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(getContext(), signInAccount);
        resourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getContext(), signInAccount);
        if(progressBar != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the currently selected Drive file's metadata and contents.
     */
    private void loadCurrentFile() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Retrieving...");
        final DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();

        // Retrieve and store the file metadata and contents.
        resourceClient.getMetadata(file)
                .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Metadata, Task<DriveContents>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<DriveContents> then(@NonNull Task<Metadata> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            metadata = task.getResult();
                            return resourceClient.openFile(file, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                        } else {
                            return Tasks.forException(task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveContents>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DriveContents contents) {
                driveContents = contents;
                refreshUiFromCurrentFile();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to retrieve file metadata and contents.", e);
            }
        });
    }


    //converting inputstream to string
    private void refreshUiFromCurrentFile() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing...");
        String contents = "";

        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(driveContents.getInputStream(), writer);
             contents = writer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(contents.trim().isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

    }




   private boolean isConnectedToTheInternet(){
       ConnectivityManager cm =
               (ConnectivityManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       boolean isConnected = false;
       try{
           NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                   activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
       }catch (SecurityException  e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        return isConnected;

   }


    private boolean isUserSignedInToGoogleDriveAccount(){
        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());
        if(signInAccount == null){
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    private void openSignInGoogleDriveAccountDialog(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No google account selected");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please sign in to Google Drive Account by pressing Google Drive Settings button");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void openPleaseConnectToInternet(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("!Internet Connection needed");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please Connect to the internet");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, i figured the problem. To use google drive API, one has to set OAuth 2.0 credentials.  I set the credentials for the debug version of my application, so the API worked as needed. The problem occurred when I tried to use the same credentials for the release version. This is a problem because you need SHA-1 key to setup the O-Auth 2.0 credentials. The debug and release versions have different SHA-1 keys.